# I don't understand how Joomla components are structured

Tags: joomla

Hello I write this because I started with the Joomla! [component development tutorial](https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component/Introduction/es) and I am lost. I have use MVC pattern in other developments and the idea is always the same: model store data, the view ask for data and the controller manage that data flow.

The problem is that in Joomla it is a mess. I have done 5 points of the tutorial, getting data from data base, and without using a Controller. When you have to render a view you have a view.html that does not contain the html code and then, a default.php that contains it. After this, when you start using Controllers, to me, is a party of files randomly placed in different folders. I don't understand a thing because they explain too few appart from "place this file in this route" or add these lines in this file.

So can anybody who understand their implementation of MVC pattern explain it to me? Thanks in advance =)

Comment: I agree with OP: the vanilla Joomla MVC does not make much sense. I cannot directly answer OP's question, but back when I developed for Joomla, I used the [JoomlaTools Framework]( http://developer.joomlatools.com/framework/getting-started.html). Check out the getting started guide in the link. It uses a HMVC standard that makes more sense than the vanilla Joomla 'framework'.



Disclaimer: the JoomlaTools framework is a third party framework on top of Joomla. I do not develop for them, but I used it in the past.

Comment: The Joomla MVC is easy to understand , but it difficult to explain, the best example is take a look at Joomla's core component com_content on front end and back end, just go through the code so you will get grip on the MVC pattern of joomla.

Comment: Ok I would take a look at both while I get another answer. Thanks

Comment: I took a look to the com_content and I am now even more lost than before. They follow a different structure that the structure you have to follow in the tutorial. 
@derjoachim I have to develope a XMLRCP component for a project that is already in production so I think that implement a framework to that would be a mess.
So please, somebody help me